# How to convert Any to Int in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an attribute in my model defined as above that in some cases contain an Int.

```
var value: Any?
```

I know that I can do it if I cast first to String and then to Int

```
value.toString().toInt() // works
```

Is there a way of doing it by skipping casting into a String before?
When I try to cast directly to into an Int I get this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: What do you mean by "try to cast directly to Int"? I don't see the code for that here. Are you simply trying to do: `value.toInt()`? Or are you attempting an explicit cast: `(Integer)value`?

Comment: From the example, it seems like that the `var` called `value` sometimes contains a String which happens contain an Int. If this is the case, you have to first cast it to String, and then parse it, for example, with the `toInt` method, as you already did.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche I was attempting do value as Int

Comment: If you do `value as? Int`, then the result will be safe cast to `Int?` (if value is `Int` the result will be the value, otherwise it will be `null`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that you were attempting to *cast* directly from a String to an Int with `value as Int`.

This isn't working because, as the exception is telling you, `value` contains a String, and a String cannot be coerced into an Int. The fact that this String represents an integer doesn't matter, as it would need to be parsed into an Int. That precisely is what the `toInt()` method does.

The reason you must cast to a String first is because `toInt()` is an extension method on String, and `value` is of type `Any?`. This means that you can't call `toInt()` directly on `value` because it doesn't know that it contains a String at compile time, even though it does at runtime. If you wanted to skip this step, you could also use smart casts by checking the type first:

```
if (value is String) {
    value.toInt()
}
```

You can find a bit more info on smart casts and other Kotlin type casting here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts

This also may be pointing to an underlying design problem. You expect that this will *sometimes* contain an Int, but as we can see here whatever is setting this value in your model is setting it to a String containing that number. Do you expect this value to truly be able to contain many different types, or are you only expect Int and String? If the latter, then it would possibly be a better design decision to make this a String rather than an `Any?`. That would prevent unexpected/unhandled types from being provided, and make the model less ambiguous to anyone looking at or using it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. value can be a String, an Int or some other data type. That part of my model needs a revision for sure.

Comment: @pablobu I updated the answer slightly to reflect what you were doing and to suggest smart casts. If you will be handling multiple data types, smart casts for each accepted type would be the best way to avoid getting into an unexpected state.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche In the same lines, how to convert Any to LinkedTreeMap in Kotlin?

Answer (score 10):

This is the way I do it:

`val myInt = value as? Int ?: defaultValue`

This will try to convert value to an int, but if it fails, will use `defaultValue` instead.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Kotlin's `toInt()` or `toIntOrNull()` method to convert from **String** to **Int** type. For example:

```
fun giveString(): String {
    return "12"
}

fun giveInt(): Int {
    return giveString().toInt()  // here we are casting return type to Int
}
```

Below we are casting return tye to `Int` if the string is not convertible, will return `null`

```
fun giveNullableInt(): Int? {
    return giveString().toIntOrNull()
}
```

Comment: Correct, but in the case of the question the variable type is Any not String, that's why we need to check if it is a string first as in @PseudoPsyche answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to covert Any to Int:-

```
fun getMyIntValue(vararg any: Any) : Int {
        return when(val tmp = any.first()) {
            is Number -> tmp.toInt()
            else -> throw Exception("not a number") // or do something else reasonable for your case
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only converts any *Number* type to `Int`. What is the best way depends on the use case. In the OP's case it wouldn't convert the string. Btw. you have a vararg but only use the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following solution works without intermediate string cast:

```
fun castToIntSafely(value: Any?): Int? = (value as? Number)?.toInt()
```